# drupal_add_css works on one server but not another?

Tags: css, drupal

I have a piece of code that works properly on my staging server, but it doesnt work properly on my localhost.  I have this file in my module `john.module`

```
drupal_add_css($filename . ".css");
```

On my staging server, `$filename` has the value `/sites/all/modules/john/style.css` .  When I do a view-source of the page, i see that there's both a `@import` statement for the style sheet and it is also mentioned as json data into the `jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings)` .

On my localhost, i was careful to recreate the file directory structure that's on staging.  The `$filename` has the same value.  However, when I do a view source of the page, I do NOT see the @import statement for the stylesheet.  However, it is mentioned in the json data in the `jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings)`.  If comment out the `drupal_add_css($filename.".css")` command above, then it also removes mention of the stylesheet in the json data.

I've cleared the cache to make sure it's not a caching issue.

So my question is, why is the stylesheet showing up on staging but not on my localhost?

ADDITIONAL NOTES

I conducted an experiment and listed results here:

```
// when i use this line the css file is NOT included and I do NOT see an @import statement in the html document
drupal_add_css('/sites/all/modules/john/style.css')

// when i use this line the css file is successfully imported
drupal_add_css('sites/all/modules/john/style.css')

// when i use this line the css file is NOT included and I do NOT see an @import statement in the html document
drupal_add_css('http://johnwebsite.com/sites/all/modules/john/style.css');

// when i use this line the css file is NOT included but I do see an @import statement in the html document
drupal_add_css('/var/www/sites/all/modules/john/style.css');
```

So why does the first rule work on my staging server but not my localhost?

Comment: Check again if your css file is added to your localhost by entering the localhost url. If you can review your css file, add exactly the same path (server+$filename.".css") and check if the Jquery library is added to your project.

Comment: @Romain - Thanks i did more research and added more notes to my question